# Null Pointer Exception in LogCat

Tags: android

I followed the code on http://www.xatik.com/2012/03/19/android-preloaded-database/
but I keep on getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
//my main activity class 
public class PrepopSqliteDbActivity extends Activity {

ExternalDbOpenHelper bHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

//Our key helper

bHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this);
bHelper.initializeDatabase("/data/data/com.catholic.arnold/databases/");

//all hymns are fetched 
final Cursor cursor = bHelper.fetchAllHymns();

// The desired columns to be bound
String[] columns = new String[] {

     ExternalDbOpenHelper.HYMN_ID,
     ExternalDbOpenHelper.HYMN_NAME,
};

// the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
int[] to = new int[] {
R.id.tVid,
R.id.name,

};

// create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
//as well as the layout information
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
this, R.layout.main,
cursor,
columns,
to,
0);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// Assign adapter to ListView
 listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
int position, long id) {
 }
  });
 bHelper.close();
}

}
```

Below is my logcat:

```
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start activity ComponentInfo {com.catholic.arnold/com.catholic.arnold.PrepopSqliteDbActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at com.catholic.arnold.ExternalDbOpenHelper.fetchAllHymns(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:110)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at com.catholic.arnold.PrepopSqliteDbActivity.onCreate(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java:30)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-17 11:54:59.360: E/AndroidRuntime(11549): ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is at at `com.catholic.arnold.PrepopSqliteDbActivity.onCreate(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java:30)`? Line No : 30.

Comment: THat is where my constructor is.. public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.questionDbVersion));
      mContext = context;
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

Answer (score 0):

`context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.questionDbVersion`

is causing NullPointerException because you haven't created `R.integer.questionDbVersion` in your project `value folder`.

Change

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.questionDbVersion))
```

to

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1))
```

Comment: wow so now we should also find out which line is causing you the error. Can't you point to the line causing the exception!

Comment: sorry about that........... I public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context) { super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.questionDbVersion)); mContext = context; // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub }

Comment: If your problem is solved, accept the answer so the question is in solve state.

Comment: actually I created R.integer.questionDbVersion in the value folder.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
bHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this);
```

with

```
bHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.this);
```